# What size Screw/Nail should I use for a 6 lb painting in drywall?

Tags: drywall, screws, hanging

I am sure you experts get tired of questions like these, but I'm a complete newbie when it comes to hanging things on drywall.

I ordered a piece of [framed wall art](http://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/product/americanflat-spires-cyvyryng-wall-art/1044046477?skuId=44046477), which is listed at 6 lbs. If I'm hanging this on drywall, do I use a nail, a screw, or a drywall anchor? It's on a small wall where I won't be able to find a stud.

This is a rental unit and I have no idea how thick the drywall is.

Answer (score 1):

At 6 pounds, a simple [picture hook](http://www.homedepot.com/p/OOK-20-lb-Steel-Brass-Plated-Conventional-Picture-Hooks-8-Pack-50452/100171123?MERCH=REC-_-PIPHorizontal1_rr-_-100210423-_-100171123-_-N) will do.  Any box store or hardware store will have them and they will list their load rating on them.  Working from memory, I think the smallest size has a 10 pound rating.

Comment: I agree that a picture hook is adequate, although I'm always a little dubious of the weight ratings. I would probably opt for a 2- or 3-nail version over the smallest.

Comment: They make 30 pound one nail hooks, those are more than necessary.  The ratings on nails, hooks and fasteners for drywall are all based on a hanging weight, not a pull out weight.  A picture is a perfect hanging weight.

Comment: A six pound picture is nothing for a wall hanger. The weight ratings are posted right on the packaging. The OP may want to opt for the next size up, say instead of 5-10 lbs, opt up to the 10-15 lb. It is still a dinky single nail hanger that will do the job very well.

Comment: I guess you guys are more confidant than I am! Here's a warning from a Home Depot picture hook: "Weight ratings are based on hangers nailed into studs and are for comparative purposes only, choose a weight rating that greatly exceeds the object to be hung".

Comment: The vast majority of picture hangers in the 20lb and under, the nail isn't even long enough to go into the stud through the drywall.  1/2 inch drywall will require a 3/4 inch nail to pierce the drywall and what is left sticking out is about 1/16 of an inch (this is at a 45deg angle).  Not enough for any bite into wood.